# How to update a select box based on radio button check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, html-select

When I click the "Non-technical" radio button I'd like to update the options of 
select box to "English", "History", "Maths". Both the radio buttons and select box are 
inside a form. This is my code given below in HTML.

I need a JavaScript validation:

```
<tr>
    <td>Category:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" checked="yes" />Technical
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Non-technical</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Branch</td>
    <td>
        <select id="techy">
            <option>Hardware</option>
            <option>Networking</option>
            <option>Linux</option>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: We're not here to do work for you, you have to try first, then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both of the select lists in your markup and only show the relevant one depending on the radio button that is chosen. That's better than manipulating the contents of the `<select>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/9NJ6t/2/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Category:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="radio-techy" type="radio" name="category" value="1" checked="yes" />Technical
            <input id="radio-non-techy" type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Non-technical
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Branch</td>
        <td>
            <div id="select-div" class="tech">
                <select id="techy">
                    <option>Hardware</option>
                    <option>Networking</option>
                    <option>Linux</option>
                </select>
                <select id="non-techy">
                    <option>English</option>
                    <option>History</option>
                    <option>Maths</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#select-div select {
    display:none;
}

#select-div.tech #techy {
    display:block;
}

#select-div.non-tech #non-techy {
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var techButton = document.getElementById('radio-techy');
var nonTechButton = document.getElementById('radio-non-techy');

techButton.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('select-div').className = 'tech';
}
nonTechButton.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('select-div').className = 'non-tech';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you could try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Category:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radioTech" name="category" value="1" checked="yes" />Technical
            <input type="radio" id="radioNonTech" name="category" value="2" />Non-technical</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Branch</td>
        <td>
            <select id="options"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**In a script tag or in a file.js**

```
// This is a literal object (JSON), if you want to add more items you just have to add them here.
options = {
    'technical': [
        'Hardware',
        'Networking',
        'Linux'
     ],
    'ntechnical': [
        'English',
        'History',
        'Maths'
     ]
};

var renderItems = function( arrItems, selectElement ){

  selectElement.innerHTML = '';

    for( var i = 0, l = arrItems.length; i < l; i++ )
    {
        var item = document.createElement( 'option' );
            item.innerHTML = arrItems[i];
        selectElement.appendChild( item );
    }

};

window.onload = function() {

    var radioTechnical = document.getElementById( 'radioTech' );
    var radioNonTechnical = document.getElementById( 'radioNonTech' );
    var selectElement = document.getElementById( 'options' );

    radioTechnical.onclick = function(){ renderItems( options.technical, selectElement ) };
    radioNonTechnical.onclick = function(){ renderItems( options.ntechnical, selectElement ) };

    radioTechnical.click();

};
```

In this example you are adding the items dynamically and if you want, it gives you the possibility of getting data from an external resource and adding it to the JSON object, after that the rest of the work is done, and the items in the array are shown =D